# my function returns null even though I have correctly instantiated the values correctly

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function inside my user_Activity.kt for the profile page of my app. This function gets the values from my firebase database, but it returns null on my profile page inside the app.

```
private fun loadUserDetails() {
    //db ref to fetch user info
    val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    dbRef.child(firebaseAuth.uid!!)
        .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("FirebaseData", "Snapshot: $snapshot")

                val email = snapshot.child("email").value.toString()
                val username = snapshot.child("username").value.toString()
                val uid = snapshot.child("id").value.toString()

                Log.d("FirebaseData", "Email: $email, Username: $username, UID: $uid")

                binding.profileUID.text = uid
                binding.profileEmail.text = email
                binding.profileUsername.text = username
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("FirebaseError", "Error: $error")
            }
        })
    }
```

The result inside logcat:

[image: Result from logcat]

What it looks like on the app:

[App result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB3Uv.png)

My database:

[image: Firebase preview]

It is supposed to return the values indicated on my firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Users` node contains a `-Nl0o...` key under it, but your `onDataChange` code isn't handling it. Even if there's only a single child node, you still need to handle that as a list of one child in your code.

If you look at the documentation on [listening for a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), you can see that the right way to handle this is:

```
dbRef.child(firebaseAuth.uid!!)
    .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val email = userSnapshot.child("email").value.toString()
                val username = userSnapshot.child("username").value.toString()
                val uid = userSnapshot.child("id").value.toString()

                Log.d("FirebaseData", "Email: $email, Username: $username, UID: $uid")
                ...
```

Comment: Hello I have implemented the code on my project and instead of null, it throws the word placehoder instead of the actual value. Is there any way to resolve this? thank you kind sir

Comment: First off: does the explanation of why your code didn't work in my answer make sense? And does it also make sense why the code in my answer would fix that specific problem? --- There may be other problems, but this was definitely one of them. If you still have problems, I recommend debugging those on your system. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?